# Пересоздаются ли объекты при передаче их функциям? (Python)

Tags: python, ооп, классы, дерево, методы

Я знаю про фишку в python, про изменяемые и неизменяемые объекты. Вопрос только в том, пересоздаются ли объекты при передаче их методам? Если я, например, создам класс вершины дерева и создам метод, добавляющий в поле экземпляра класса родительский элемент - будет ли пересоздаваться этот родительский элемент? Иными словами,

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.parent = None

    def add_parent(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent

root = Test()
child = Test()
child.add_parent(root)
```

Будет ли здесь пересоздаваться объект **root**?

Comment: конечно нет **.**

Comment: А дополнительно память не будет затрачиваться на создание нового экземпляра класса, который добавится в поле, которое должно содержать родительский элемент? То есть, здесь это будет работать как ссылка на родительский элемент?

Comment: что вам мешает самому проверить? заодно и подкачаете скиллы. Ну т.е. вы можете просто создать хамельон объектов одним способом, замерить память, создать такой же хамельон вторым способом.

Comment: Я не знаю как. Максимум, что я могу придумать, чтобы проверить - создать 1000 экземпляров вот этого тестового класса и попробовать проверить начальное и конечное состояние оперативы. Только вот я не пойму, если мое предположение оказалось верным или я создал недостаточно экземпляров класса

Comment: @Semior я же уже ответил - нет, не будет; да, это будет ссылка

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Только вот я вопрос не могу закрыть

Comment: Related: [In Python, why can a function modify some arguments as perceived by the caller, but not others?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/575196/4279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверить можно просто распечатав объект через `print`. Там адрес будет виден. Более красивый способ — использовать фунцию `id`.
В любом случае тут можно просто сравнить адреса.

```py
>>> def print_obj(name, obj):
...     print (name, obj, id(obj))
... 
>>> class Test(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         print_obj('self = ', self)
...         self.parent = None
...     def add_parent(self, parent):
...         print_obj('parent = ', parent)
...         self.parent = parent
... 
>>> root = Test()
self =  <__main__.Test object at 0x7f84c761bbe0> 140208257481696
>>> child = Test()
self =  <__main__.Test object at 0x7f84c761bcf8> 140208257481976
>>> child.add_parent(root)
parent =  <__main__.Test object at 0x7f84c761bbe0> 140208257481696
```